# Dependency Injection in a ASP.NET Custom Server Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, custom-server-controls

I am writing some asp.net custom server controls and looking for the best practice as to how to inject a dependency that the control needs.

When deciding on how to do this, there are a couple of factors which I am taking into consideration: 
1) How easy would it be to inject this dependency through markup.
2) How easy would it be to inject this dependency through code-behind.
3) This injection has to be as early as possible in the control life cycle, preferably the control should have all of its dependencies available in the OnInit().

Bases on these factors, the only way I can think of doing this it so have a string property on the control which will have the fully qualities type to the dependency. Once the control initializes it can load that type and do what it needs to do. 
**Example**:

```
public class MyControl : CompositeControl
{     

     public string RepositoryType { get; set; }     
     protected IRepository Repository { get; set; }

     protected override void OnInit()
     {
          EnsureChildControls();
     }

     protected override void CreateChildControls()
     {
          if (!ChildControlsCreated)
          {
              Repository = ComponentFactory.Instanciate(RepositoryType);
          }
     }
}
```

I run into this kind of situation all the time and was wondering if anyone else
figured out another/better/different to inject the dependency. 
Thanks :)

Comment: Have you looked at any Dependency Injection frameworks like Unity or NInject?  These will automatically inject a concrete class for you at runtime based on how you configure it.

Comment: For right now, I would rather not add another variable (framework) into the system. Maybe in the future I will check them out.

Comment: This depends on how you're instantiating the control.  If it's dynamically loaded via the code-behind, then dependency injection works differently if you were to let the server load it via an asp tag (in one you have the instance, the other is behind the scenes).  If loading via the asp tag, in some frameworks you can apply an attribute like `[Inject]` to the property to tell your injector which dependencies to populate.

Comment: @BlueChameleon I understand that logic, but you are basically re-creating the wheel.  NInject in particular is a very lightweight DI framework that is much better tested and more robust than something you design "just to get it to work".  You'd teach yourself a new tool that will be useful in future projects, and avoid any bugs created by your custom-written DI system.  I'm not saying you're not a capable developer, but when you have the opportunity to, stand on the shoulders of giants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've done is on init of the control, query the DI container and populate those references.  You could nest this logic in a specialized base class that your custom server control can inherit from, so then it's reused.  OR: There is a special [AddedControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.addedcontrol.aspx) method that is called everytime a control is added to the control tree.  The caveat here is that it probably only calls the method on the parent control, and does not propogate up.  It may work depending on your scenario.

There isn't much in the lifecycle that lets you know when a control is created (other than the AddedControl method or the Init method that runs at the beginning of the process) to be able to tap into, and you can't customize the constructor of the control.

In regards to #1, to use the markup approach would require tapping into the design-time aspect of controls, and leveraging the design time attributes to the fullest.  But #1 means defining the mappings in markup, which is not quite the point of a DI container.  The designer still needs the property or something to assign the reference to, so it would essentially be double work of defining the property, then defining something  in the designer, when the DI container takes care of that for you.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your solution does not take into consideration of how to set the DIs from markup.

Comment: That's true.  Edited above.

Comment: You are right about the markup. It does not make sense to assign dependencies from markup. I guess the whole thing with DI is that I am always getting twisted between components being self container and still expendable. Thanks